# Sequelize assign query parameters to Model

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have several models imported in a controller file that I use to query Sequelize.

```
const ModelA = require('../models/ModelA')
const ModelB = require('../models/ModelB')
```

I want to create an API (with express and NodeJS) that allows a query parameter called includes.

GET /api/v1/myrequest?includes=ModelA,ModelB

The includes are optional.

I generate a queryObject:

```
const { include } = query.params      
const queryObject = {}
      queryObject.include = [{
        model: Model,
        as: 'Model',
        include: include ? include.split(',') : [] // either ModelA, ModelB, none or both
      }
      ]
```

It doesn't work because the dynamic include query is just an array. But what I want is to map the real models that I have imported to the req.query request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All models should be registered in Sequelize beforehand. That way you can do the following:

```
include.split(',').map(x => sequelize.models[x])
```